# Get the TFS 2015 Work Item Hierarchy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api, tfs-2015

I'm trying to create a report in Tableau to generate a tree structure of all the work items in TFS 2015 and their respective hierarchy
Such as

Epic->Features->User Story->Task

But repeated attempts to create the sql query have failed. Could you please help me with the SQL query that could help fetch all the work items and display their hierarchy?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to be more specific than that.  Show what work you currently have or the attempts you have tried. You are much more likely to get a response this way.

Comment: From where are you trying to query them from? `tfs_warehouse`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried from the TFS_Warehouse and was able toget relation from epic to feature link, but its incomplete since I wanted complete drilldown from Epic to Task, but am unable to achieve so.  The SQL Query I made is:  SELECT distinct DWI.System_Id,DWI.System_Title
,FWILH.TargetWorkItemID ,WorkItemLinkTypeSK
FROM DimWorkItem DWI  
INNER JOIN FactWorkItemLinkHistory FWILH ON DWI.System_Id = FWILH.SourceWorkItemID
 WHERE FWILH.WorkItemLinkTypeSK IN (SELECT DWILT.WorkItemLinkTypeSK FROM DimWorkItemLinkType DWILT WHERE DWILT.LinkID = 2)
 AND FWILH.RemovedDate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have found this query, which is working and can help you create a tableau workbook for the hierarchy:

```
 WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeName ,
                        System_WorkItemType ,
                        DimWorkItem.System_Id ,
                        FactWorkItemLinkHistory.TargetWorkItemID ,
                        DimWorkItem.System_Title,
                        DimWorkItem.System_State,
                        DimWorkItem.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ActivatedDate,
                        DimWorkItem.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_TargetDate,
                        DimWorkItem.System_CreatedDate,
                        DimWorkItemLinkType.LinkName,
                        TeamProjectSK,
                        system_rev,
                        row_number() over( partition by system_id,TeamProjectSK, FactWorkItemLinkHistory.TargetWorkItemID order by system_rev desc ) rownum
               FROM     DimWorkItem ,
                        DimTeamProject ,
                        FactWorkItemLinkHistory,
                        DimWorkItemLinkType
               WHERE    DimWorkItem.TeamProjectSK = DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeSK 
                        AND DimWorkItem.System_Id = FactWorkItemLinkHistory.SourceWorkItemID
                        and DimWorkItemLinkType.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = FactWorkItemLinkHistory.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
                        /*    -To Test the Query using the project Name of our choice-    */
                        --AND ProjectNodeName =
                        AND System_State in ('ACTIVE','NEW')
                        /* -System Revisions are created when the entry is modified. Onlt the latest entry will have the below revised date-  */
                        AND System_RevisedDate = '9999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
                        AND DimWorkItemLinkType.Linkname IN ( 'Parent',
                                                     'child' )
               GROUP BY DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeName ,
                        DimWorkItem.System_Id ,
                        FactWorkItemLinkHistory.TargetWorkItemID ,
                        DimWorkItem.System_Title ,
                        System_WorkItemType,
                        DimWorkItem.System_State,
                        TeamProjectSK,
                        DimWorkItemLinkType.LINKName,
                        DimWorkItem.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ActivatedDate,
                        DimWorkItem.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_TargetDate,
                        DimWorkItem.System_CreatedDate,
                        system_rev
             )
    SELECT distinct t1.ProjectNodeName ,
            t1.System_Id requirement_Id ,
            t1.System_WorkItemType,
            t1.System_Title requirement_title ,
            t2.System_Id Change_request_id ,
            t1.LinkName,
            t2.System_Title Change_Request_Title,
            t1.Microsoft_VSTS_Common_ActivatedDate,
            t1.System_CreatedDate,
            t1.Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_TargetDate,
            t1.System_State,
            T1.rownum
    FROM    cte t1
            INNER JOIN cte t2 ON t1.TargetWorkItemID = t2.System_Id
                                  and t1.rownum = 1

    ORDER BY t1.System_Id;
```

Used a CTE to find get the complete hierarchy, its faster and more efficient than the query posted before.

Comment: Ty for confirming that system_revdate is at that weird number when its the live version... I have spent months trying to figure out what the live version is

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SQL Query, it's suggested to use [TFS REST API to create a query](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#create-a-query) in TFS, the WIQL looks like:

```
"wiql": "select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItemLinks where (Source.[System.TeamProject] = 'xxx' and Source.[System.WorkItemType] <> '' and Source.[System.State] <> '') and ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') and (Target.[System.WorkItemType] <> '') order by [System.Id] mode (Recursive)"
```

Comment: I wanted to, but I have to create a dashboard in Tableau which requires me to use the SQL Query and Im not sure we could use the API directly into Tableau